# How to show active submenu on mouseout/mouseleave?

Tags: jquery

I need to make the submenu to show when I mouseout/mouseleave another link in my topmenu.How do I do that? I dont know so much jQuery I hava actually learned alot from stackoverflow. Just so you all know :)

I have tried to use a mouseover function and on mouseover but havent made it work. I know I need to find out what the current location href and apply a hover class to it when I mouseleave but don't really know how to write it.
Here is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

/*Adress för startsidan*/
var aktAdress = " ";
aktAdress = "http://localhost/2.612e0c6d167074c5746163.html";
/*Hover funktion för första sidan*/
if (location.href == aktAdress) {
    $(".nav div").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).addClass("hover");
        },
        function() {
            $(this).removeClass("hover");
        }
    );
    /*Toggleknapp funktion för visning av undermeny och
    ur fokusering ut för att dölja undermeny efter sista tab
    på sista länken*/
    $("button").click(function() {
        $(this).closest(".nav div").toggleClass("hover");
    });
    $("div.sub div.child:last-child").focusout(function() {
        $(".nav div").removeClass("hover");
    });

} else if (location.href != aktAdress);
/*Visar undermenyn som matchar toppmenylänken*/
$(".nav div [href]").each(function() {
    if (this.href == window.location.href) {
        $(this).parent().css({
            "background": "#d2d2d2",
            "color": "white"
        });
        $(this).parent().addClass("hover");
        $("div.sub div.child:last-child").focusout(function() {
            $(".nav div").removeClass("hover");
        });
        /*Toggleknapp funktion för nivå 2 undermeny
                och döjlning av aktiv undermeny*/
        $(".nav div").on("click", "button", function() {
            $(".nav div.hover").toggleClass("hover");
            $(this).closest(".nav div").toggleClass("hover");

        });
       /*Mouseover funktion för att dölja nivå 2 aktiv undermeny*/
        $(".nav div").mouseover(function(){
           $(".nav div.hover").toggleClass("hover");
            $(this).closest(".nav div").toggleClass("hover");
});
    }
    /*Hover funktion på menyn för sidorna arkiv,övrigt och evenemang*/
    else if ((window.location.href.indexOf("http://localhost/arkiv/") > -1) ||
        (window.location.href.indexOf("http://localhost/ovrigt/") > -1) ||
        (window.location.href.indexOf("http://localhost/evenemangtest/") > -1)) {
        $(".nav div").hover(
            function() {
                $(this).addClass("hover");
            },
            function() {
                $(this).removeClass("hover");
            }
        );

    }
    /*Visar matchande undermeny för nivå 3 samt aktiv länk*/
    else ($(".nav div div [href]").each(function() {
            if (this.href == window.location.href) {
                $(this).parents().eq(3).addClass("hover");
                $(this).parents().eq(3).css("background", "#d2d2d2");
                $(this).css({
                    "background": "black",
                    "color": "#d2d2d2"
                });
                $(this).hover(function() {
                    return false;
                });
            }
        }));
});

});
```

I expect when a user leaves with the mouse on another link the current active link that matches the url shall get the hover class. Now the active link and submenu gets the hover state toggled off when a user mouseover another link. I would be grateful if someone can help me:)

Answer (score 0):

So after alot of trying I have finally found the solution to my problem by writing the following code.

Jquery:

```
/*Mouseover to hide page 2 active submenu*/
        $(".nav div").mouseover(function () {
            $(".nav div.hover").toggleClass("hover");
            $(this).closest(".nav div").addClass("hover");
        });
     /*Mouseout function to show the active submenu after the user
     has their pointer over another link and then leave that link*/
     $(".nav div").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).closest(".nav div").toggleClass("hover");
        $(".nav div.active").addClass("hover");
     });
```

Maybe someone can you use this code to. Enjoy:)